# How to add "-" inside string values in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am having difficulties with a column while practicing,

the values in the column should be dates, however, they are written as YYYYMMDD(e.g 20200101).

How do I make the integer into datetime format such as YYYY-MM-DD or 2020-01-01?

Having a hard time with this.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: it only changed the values into 1970-01-01. The dtype of the date is "Int64".

Comment: OK, can you test `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')` ?

Comment: still didn't work, got the same result as last time

Comment: `still didn't work` Can you be more specific? Some error?

Comment: the result was still all 1970-01-01, uncoverted data remains :99

Comment: OK, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), mainly add some dates which are wrongly parsed.

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d'),  this works fine, if you are using jupyter then try cleaning and restarting the kernal